# Could not find "tools.jar' in the active JRE

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

[image]

Spring Boot Live hovers will not work without it.

The JRE you are running Eclipse with is: -----

Where we looked for 'tools.jar':------

Comment: tools.jar is only included in the JDK, it is not in the JRE

Answer (score 1):

Just copy file `tools.jar` from `"..\jdk1.8\lib\"` to `"..\jre1.8\lib\"`